# Add panel dynamically c#

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-2.0

I'm trying to add panels to groupbox, the panels will have a backgroundimage.

I have three files, so I should have 3 panels in the groupbox, but 4 panels be  displayed with the same photo . I am using the following code:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
        FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles();
        Point NewPosition =new Point() ;

        foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
        {
            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(folder+@"\"+ fi.Name);

            Panel p = new Panel();
            p.Size = b.Size;
            p.BackgroundImage = b;
            p.Name = fi.Name;
            p.Dock = DockStyle.Top;



            control.Controls.Add(p);

        }
```

Any suggestions please.

Comment: @Cory, he stated only one is being displayed.

Comment: What type is 'control' variable? Also i do not see any positioning of panels, so maybe they are on each other and only last is visible (hiding others below)?

Comment: @Dustin: My apologies, I read the "but only one is displayed" as "but only one should be displayed".

Comment: how to change the panel position there're no panel postion property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not setting the location of the panels.

I'm guessing the panels are being stacked on top of each other making the top panel the only panel viable.

Panel has a **Location** property which you can set.  You can also dock your panels using the **Dock** property.

Couple of quick examples:

```
p.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
```

or

```
p.Location = new Point(50, 50);
```

Comment: how to change the location dynamically please , I don't know how many panels I have in the grooupbox

Comment: all created controls are in same location. set the location for each control.

Comment: the dock worked but the result is four panels with the same background I updated my code in my question code u help me in that